# Excel VB deleting rows when no value found

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently designing a small workbook to move work between sheets when allocated. I've written a small code which is supposed to scan the sheet from row A7 onwards for a keyword and then move the row to either Sheet 5 or Sheet 6 based on the value.

However, now I have added more auto filters to the code, the script seems to be deleting rows from a1 and moving them to Sheet 5 and 6 in error which is destroying the formatting. I've duplicated the code for the 5 different keywords which is possibly where the error occurs...does anyone know why?

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Columns(11).AutoFilter 1, "ORNC"
With Range("a7", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(3))
    .Copy Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1)
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With
Columns(11).AutoFilter

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Columns(11).AutoFilter 1, "ORCIF"
With Range("a7", Range("k" & Rows.Count).End(3))
    .Copy Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1)
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With
Columns(11).AutoFilter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Columns(11).AutoFilter 1, "OP Write Off"
With Range("a7", Range("k" & Rows.Count).End(3))
    .Copy Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1)
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With
Columns(11).AutoFilter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Columns(11).AutoFilter 1, "LO Write Off"
With Range("a7", Range("k" & Rows.Count).End(3))
    .Copy Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1)
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With
Columns(11).AutoFilter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Columns(11).AutoFilter 1, "Not a Recon"
With Range("a7", Range("k" & Rows.Count).End(3))
    .Copy Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1)
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With
Columns(11).AutoFilter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

As you can see, the script should look for one of the keywords in column K from row 7 onwards, and then move to Sheet 5/6 based on its return.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Graeme

Comment: Instead of copypasta, why not use a `select case` statement?  Switching to that may help find/resolve whatever error you have elsewhere.

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php

Comment: Have you tried [stepping through your code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).  This method allows you to see the impact each line of code has on your worksheets.  You should be able to track down the offending line in no time.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of stepping through the code...I've narrowed it down to the  '.EntireRow.Delete' code when the script finds no valid rows for the filter its searching for. For example, when the script filters for "OP Write Off" and there are no rows with that in, its going to Row1 and moving that row to the designated sheet. It should be disregarding that part of the code as there's nothing to move ( no value found ).

Comment: You might also try adding an explicit sheet for each statement involving columns. The statements as they stand might act on the wrong sheet.

Comment: Protip: [edit] your title so that it describes the problem in some kind of searchable way. the current title is applicable to 60,960 questions on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've edited the title now.